# Using formik with typescript (Ionic)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, formik

I try to use Formik library for validating forms however I have trouble passing onChange function to my input components.

Here is the main component:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { IonHeader, IonContent, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonButton, IonPage, IonList } from '@ionic/react';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';

import BasicInput from '../components/form/BasicInput';

const Login: React.FC = () => {

    const validate = (values: {
        name: string;
    }) => {
        const errors = {};
        if (!values.name) {

        }

        return errors;
    }

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: ''
        },
        validateOnChange: false,
        validateOnBlur: false,
        validate,
        onSubmit: values => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        },
    })

    const {
        name
    } = formik.values

    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonTitle>Login</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonContent>
                <IonList>
                    <BasicInput
                        id="name"
                        placeholder={"Your name"}
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    />

                </IonList>

                <div>
                    <IonButton onClick={handleLogin}>
                        Done
                    </IonButton>
                </div>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    )
     }

    export default Login;
```

And here is my input component:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { IonInput, IonItem } from '@ionic/react';

const BasicInput: React.FC<{
    id: string,
    placeholder: string,
    onChange: () => any
}> = (props) => {
    return (
        <IonItem>
            <IonInput
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                onIonChange={props.onChange}
            >

            </IonInput>
        </IonItem>
    )
}

export default BasicInput;
```

Error im getting is "Type '(eventOrPath: string | ChangeEvent) => void | ((eventOrTextValue: string | ChangeEvent) => void)' is not assignable to type '() => any'."   on my onChange prop.

How to properly declare it for TS?

Comment: you can just define it as any??

Comment: @AaronSaunders Didnt I just do that? If not I am completely confused at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message indicates where is the problem.

In `BasicInput`, you are defining a prop `onChange: () => any`. But clearly, the function that is going to be called will need to receive the new input value as a parameter and does not need to return anything, so your prop definition should be something like this:

```js
{
    // ...
    onChange: (newValue: string) => void;
}
```

But, if you hover your mouse over the `onIonChange` prop of `<IonInput />`, you can see that the passed function does not receive a string as a parameter!

This is the full definition: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/976e68da5b030baf26dc60034ff80d8db2cff8e6/core/src/components.d.ts#L4137

It actually fires a [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent). Having this event `e`, you can access the input value via `e.target.value`.

The full code becomes this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { IonInput, IonItem } from '@ionic/react';

const BasicInput: React.FC<{
    id: string,
    placeholder: string,
    onChange: (newValue: string) => void
}> = (props) => {
    return (
        <IonItem>
            <IonInput
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                onIonChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
            >

            </IonInput>
        </IonItem>
    )
}

export default BasicInput;
```

Comment: It worked, however I turned off "strictNullChecks" because it had issues with "e.details.value" 
Thank you :)

Comment: Nice! I would recommend against turning this flag off, as many bugs will not be prevented. If I understand correctly, you could use the new optional chaining feature: `e.details?.value` and change the onChange handler to accept undefined values