# Angular- Disable button till dropdown option is selected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dropdown, mat-select

I made a dropdown
[image]
As you can see there are empty textareas and no option is selected. I want to disable all the buttons until any option is selected and textareas are full, means making selecting an option mandatory. How do I do it?

This is my code:

```
<div>
  <table class="justify-content-between">
    <tr *ngFor="let entity of rows">
      <td class="col-1" *ngIf="entity.value!=null">
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="entity.code" (selectionChange)="onChangeValue($event)" required>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let lang of languages" [disabled]="!lang.canEdit" [value]="lang.code" disabled>{{ lang.title }}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-1" *ngIf="entity.value!=null">
        <textarea style="height: 2rem" class="pl-5" >{{ entity.value }}</textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center mt-2">
    <button class="form-control" (click)="addNewLanguage()">Add new language</button>
      <div class="d-flex pt-2">
        <button class="form-control">Discard</button>
        <button class="form-control ml-4">Save Changes</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The ts file:

```
dialogData: DialogDataModel;

  languages: any[];

  rows: any[] = [];

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogDataModel) {
      this.dialogData = data;
      this.rows = this.dialogData.localisedEntities.filter(lang => lang.value);
      this.languages = this.dialogData.localisedEntities.map(item => ({ code: item.code, title: item.title, canEdit: item.canEdit }))
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addNewLanguage() {
    this.rows.push({
      code: '',
      title: '',
      value: '',
      canEdit: true
    });
  }

  onChangeValue(ev: any){
    this.rows = this.rows.map(row => {
      if (row.code == ev.value) {
        const lang = this.languages.find(lang => lang.code == ev.value);
        row.title =lang.title;
      }
      return row;
    });
    

    this.languages = this.languages.map(lang => {
      if (lang.code == ev.value) {
        lang.canEdit = false;
      }
      return lang;
    });

  }
```

Comment: Can you add the typescript file too with the variable you initializing, als you want to enable when all drop down and text fields are slected

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You want it to disable when all drop down and text values have no value or only when text fields

Comment: When both the drop down and textarea have no values. Like the user should not be able to add a new row, until these fields are not filled

Comment: Also please add dummy arrays of object for language and rows, i will create a fiddle for you

Comment: You can use your own data. The object is there only. Check `this.row.push` that is the structure of the object. All are string,only canEdit is boolean

Comment: i tried to replicate your problem in the answer

Comment: Did it help u to fix the issue

Comment: @KumailHussain It worked. Can you please upvote my question too, if you don't mind

Comment: yeah sure, cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237629/discussion-between-spaceboi-and-kumail-hussain).

Comment: sure let me know

Comment: How to update value in a dummy JSON, with data from the dialog box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call on `changeEvent` whenever an option is selected or text field is changed
For option selected

```
 <mat-select
            [(ngModel)]="entity.code"
            (selectionChange)="onChangeValue($event)"
            required
>
```

for text area you also need to bind the value to `ngModel`
like this

```
 <textarea
            [(ngModel)]="entity.value"
            (change)="isDisabled()"
            style="height: 2rem"
            class="pl-5"
          ></textarea>
```

and the buttons you want to disable you need to add disable property like this

```
<button
        class="form-control"
        (click)="addNewLanguage()"
        [disabled]="isDisabled()"
      >
        Add new language
      </button>

 <button class="form-control ml-4" [disabled]="isDisabled()">
          Save Changes
        </button>
```

and in ts file you need to do this

```
 onChangeValue() {
    this.isDisabled();
  }
  isDisabled() {
    return this.rows.filter((item) => item.value == '' || item.code == '')
      .length > 0
      ? true
      : false;
  }
```

you will see both are calling the same function on event change

here is the stackblitz  just for demo cahnge it as your ease https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-decme7

Answer (score -2):

Please Use Formik and Yup.
it is good solution for field validation.

you can refer about them [blog]: [Using formik with typescript (Ionic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971972/using-formik-with-typescript-ionic) "Here"